# Remove blank line between successive pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I am able to create a text file from jasper implementation. Screenshot attached, the problem being faced here is that: In the individual pages , if there are less rows, jasper is creating the page with a default height (595 px as mentioned in jrxml) which makes rows after valid rows as blank and then creates a new page.

If i change the height to a smaller number, then the rows of the first page are flowing to the next page which should not be the case.

I want the new page to start from the place where first page records end. How can i configure this dynamic nature for every page in a jrxml.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the table height, band height, in which the table component is located and the report height to be same.

Suppose if table is in detail band and table height is 50 and there is no other component in the detail band, then make detail band height to 50 and the report height to 50.